# Java Reflection: Why getConstructors() for class A returns an empty array?

Tags: java, reflection

**D.java**

```
   package com.model; 
   public class D {
     public int z;
    }
```

**B.java**

```
package com;
import com.model.D;

class A {
 public int x;
}

class C {
 public int y;
 public C() {}
}
        
public class B {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        
        Class clssA = A.class;
        Constructor[] constructorA = clssA.getConstructors();   // []
        
        Class clssC = C.class;
        Constructor[] constructorB = clssC.getConstructors();  // [public com.C()]

        Class clssD = D.class;
        Constructor[] constructorD = clssD.getConstructors();  // [public com.model.D()]
        }
}
```

As per my understanding, the Java compiler provides a default (public no-arg) constructor for classes without any constructor, then why the output of getConstrucors() call for class A and class C are different?

Also, class A and class D have the same class structure with the only difference of package name but the getConstructors() for class D returns a non-empty array?

Comment: @HenryTwist I don't see anything in your duplicate that answers this question.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Java generates a default constructor with the same access modifier as the class. [JLS #8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9). As `A` isn't public, the generated constructor isn't either: and `getConstructors()` only returns public constructors.

Comment: @user207421 Oh really? The accepted answer says only public constructors are returned and if the "class is NOT public -- its default constructor won't be either". I guess I thought that was the same as your comment (although definitely less explicit).